# PHP giving variable error when using SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session

All,
I'm trying to write a mySQL query but PHP is giving me an error. The line that is giving me an error is:

```
$qry = "Select * from vendor_options where vendor_option_id='$_SESSION[pav_vendor_categories_$i]'";
```

The above code is in a for loop so that is how the $i is getting populated. The error I'm receiving is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ']'

Any ideas on what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I will never understand why people construct their strings like that. Just concatenate or use sprintf! much tidier and cleaner.

Comment: repeated concatenation gets ugly quickly, and sprintf is far less readable in the long run.

Comment: How is sprintf less readable than doing, for example, what the OP has done? And what would you recommend to be the most readable of methods? curious....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sVendorId = $_SESSION['pav_vendor_categories_' . $i];
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM vendor_options WHERE vendor_option_id='{$sVendorId}'";
```

This your working code.
Build vendor option ID outside of query — this will make you code more readable.

Comment: if it's an id, you don't need to wrap it with the apostrophes.

Comment: MySQL will ignore them :) but if `vendor_option_id` is a string value. but you didn't escape `$sVendorId` this is a problem.

Comment: I'd just cast the value to an integer, as a way of cleaning too.

Comment: if you sure that there will be only integer, than use `intval()` and remove quotes from query.

Comment: Just because MySQL will ignore it, doesn't mean it's a good idea. It's not good practice. I'd also be concerned if a field which has the word 'id' in it is a string type. But this wouldn't surprise me....

Comment: It will be an integer so I added in the intval() and also removed the quotes from the query. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
$qry = "Select * from vendor_options where 
          vendor_option_id='{$_SESSION["pav_vendor_categories_{$i}"]}'";
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/0nHsFZ8i

Answer (score 0):

should be :

```
$qry = "Select * from vendor_options where vendor_option_id='".$_SESSION["pav_vendor_categories_".$i]."'";
```

but dont do it like that... read about [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343451/sql-injection-protection)

hope this helps

Comment: `pav_vendor_categories_$i` will throw something. (error or a warning, not sure)

Comment: @Neal, no it doesn't. I've tested `$i = 1;$_SESSION["foo1"] = "bar";echo $_SESSION["foo$i"];` it outputs "bar".. because it has double quotes =) anyway, it's kinda ugly so i've changed the code of my answer

Comment: you did not have the quotes there before.